# How to properly set email hyperlinks inside a form email in a workflow step

Tags: workflow, hyperlink

The first hyperlink works and when you open attachment the form opens with the submitter's auto populated data. The problem is when a manager approves the form it goes to me and when I open attachment my info populates instead of keeping the submitter's original info.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure the field is set to not to Refresh value when formula is recalculated. I assume this is enabled and would exhibit the behavior you are describing.